# 4 products in one row homepage

Tags: catalog, products

I want to show 4 products in one row on my Magento site.
I tried some tricks but it doesn’t work..

I set this in [list.phtml](http://pastebin.com/9jvJS9Tf)

```
<?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>
```

but nothing..

I also put this in catalog.xml

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
```

Here is my list.phtml and my [catalog.xml](http://pastebin.com/MLVgMAcZ)

This is my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/how-to-set-number-of-columns-in-category-listing-in-magento/

you can go All details as @Sander told

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the column count through the layout XML. I'm guessing your homepage is a CMS page so the block was probably added in the `Design` tab under `Layout Update XML`.

The XML syntax should look something like this for adding the list and setting the column count.

```
[...]
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setColumnCount"><count>4</count></action>
</block>
[...]
```

Comment: Yes, i add this to my cms page to show products from one category . 
'{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="14" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4""}}'

Where i need to put that blocks... 
This is my Layout Update XML http://pastebin.com/mv22uugD

Comment: ah ok, you've added it through the content editor in that case. If you print `$this->getColumnCount();` in the `list.phtml` what do you get on the homepage?

Comment: I put this in list.phtml but nothing happend.. line 92.. <?php $_columnCount = 4; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You have everything doubled in this template, as it is used for two cases. you have set it for the wrong, there should be a second where you could set it and it has effect.